# Problem passing Pipeline through nested RFECV and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to perform feature selection and grid search for the inner loop of a nested CV in sklearn. While I can pass a pipeline as the estimator to the `RFECV`, I then receive an error on fitting when I pass the `RFECV` as the estimator to `GridSearchCV`.

I have found that changing the name of the model in the pipeline to 'estimator' moves the error to the Pipeline with 'regression an invalid parameter' rather than in the `RFECV` where whatever I named the model was an invalid parameter.

I have verified using `rfcv.get_params().keys()` and `pipeline.get_params().keys()` that the parameters I'm calling do exist.

I do not receive this error if I name `SGDRegressor()` directly as ‘estimator’ and ignore the pipeline entirely, but this model requires feature scaling and log transforming of the Y variable.

```
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

import numpy as np
# random sample data
X = np.random.rand(100,2)
y = np.random.rand(100)

#passing coef amd importance through pipe and TransformedTargetRegressor
class MyPipeline(Pipeline):
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.coef_
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.feature_importances_

class MyTransformedTargetRegressor(TransformedTargetRegressor):
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self.regressor_.feature_importances_

    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self.regressor_.coef_

# build pipeline
pipeline = MyPipeline([ ('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
                     ('estimator', MyTransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=SGDRegressor(), func=np.log1p, inverse_func=np.expm1))]) 

# define tuning grid
parameters = {"estimator__regressor__alpha": [1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1], 
              "estimator__regressor__l1_ratio": [0.001,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.999]} 

# instantiate inner cv
inner_kv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
rfcv = RFECV(estimator=pipeline, step=1, cv=inner_kv, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")

cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfcv, param_grid=parameters, cv=inner_kv, iid=True,
                  scoring= "neg_mean_squared_error", n_jobs=-1, verbose=True)
cv.fit(X,y)
```

I receive the following error and can confirm that regressor is a parameter for estimator pipeline:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter regressor for estimator MyPipeline(memory=None,
           steps=[('scaler', MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))),
                  ('estimator',
                   MyTransformedTargetRegressor(check_inverse=True,
                                                func=<ufunc 'log1p'>,
                                                inverse_func=<ufunc 'expm1'>,
                                                regressor=SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001,
                                                                       average=False,
                                                                       early_stopping=False,
                                                                       epsilon=0.1,
                                                                       eta0=0.01,
                                                                       fit_intercept=True,
                                                                       l1_ratio=0.15,
                                                                       learning_rate='invscaling',
                                                                       loss='squared_loss',
                                                                       max_iter=1000,
                                                                       n_iter_no_change=5,
                                                                       penalty='l2',
                                                                       power_t=0.25,
                                                                       random_state=None,
                                                                       shuffle=True,
                                                                       tol=0.001,
                                                                       validation_fraction=0.1,
                                                                       verbose=0,
                                                                       warm_start=False),
                                                transformer=None))],
           verbose=False). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be `estimator__estimator__regressor` because you have the pipeline inside the `rfecv`.

Try this!

```py
parameters = {"estimator__estimator__regressor__alpha": [1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1], 
              "estimator__estimator__regressor__l1_ratio": [0.001,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.999]}
```

Note: Having a nested CV is not a right approach. May be you can do the feature selection separately and then do the model training.

Comment: thanks for this! I'm using a very small dataset so was hoping to have these two nested CV's as the inner train/validation loops so I could get a generalisable error from my outer CV. Is there a good method to achieve this if I take feature selection out of the nested CV? I was motivated by this approach:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/224171

Comment: It is always costly to find the ideal model hyperparameters and feature selection simultaneously. I would recommend do the feature selection with a fairly simpler model and then do the hyper parameter tuning for the model.

Comment: I've been using this anwswer, but can't save (pickle) the results: is there a way to make the `class MyPipeline(Pipeline)` serializable ("pickleable")?